# jQuery DataTables max column width

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables in my .NET web application but how do I set a max width for one specific column, all the other columns should be auto sized (like they are now in my table)

**EDIT**

The DataTables did it correctly by itself, the problem was there was a very long word without spaces that cause the problem

Comment: Yes, but i already found out what the problem was, i had an test string without any spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem seems more CSS related ...

Using **word-wrap** in CSS would fix that issue, for **columnX** just add this to your CSS.

```
.columnX {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

It would wrap even words without spaces based on your set width for the column.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/word-wrap

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the above solution of using the `word wrap` - it works great. However, I had further issues with columns with large amounts of data in. I also did the following to get it fully working:

I have had numerous issues with the column widths of `datatables`. The magic fix for me was including the line

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

This `css` goes with the overall `css` of the table. For example, if you have declared the `datatables` like the following:

```
LoadTable = $('#LoadTable').dataTable.....
```

Then the magic `css` line would go in the class `Loadtable`.

```
#Loadtable {
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. You guys Justin and you have saved my lots of time :-)

Comment: Combining this with the accepted answer works, the accepted answer alone does not.

Answer (score 1):

I am controlling the column width by modifying the contents if too long and displaying the full text in a tooltip.

```
{
    targets: [3],
    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return type === 'display' && data.length > 20 ?
        '<span title="' + data + '">' + data.substr(0, 18) + '...</span>' : data;
    }
},
{
    targets: [3],
    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="' + data + '">' + data + '</span>';
    }
}
```

Using the span element, you  could control length directly as well.

```
{
    targets: [3],
    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<span style="display: inline-block; width:200px;">' + data + '</span>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

It can be easy with use of

```
'columnDefs': [
      {'max-width': '20%', 'targets': 0}
    ],
```

Refer this link for more information.
([How to set max-width for particular column in jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763722/how-to-set-max-width-for-particular-column-in-jquery-datatables))!

Comment: The referenced link states that setting 'max-width' doesn't work.