# How to set max-width for particular column in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatable

How do I set a max width for one specific column, all the other columns should be auto sized. I have tried the below code, but it does not work since I think there is no 'max-width' attribute

```
$('#table').dataTable({
    'paging': false,
    'info': false,
    'searching': false,
    'columnDefs': [
      {'max-width': '320px', 'targets': 'my-column'}
    ],
});
```

Comment: can you check with my answer ?

Comment: `max-width` does not work for me. Also `targets` can be a css class of a column, not only an index

Comment: No need mention class name in target option, just mention position number of column, I test with my project, that is working fine

Comment: why not use the index of field in datatable ?

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this

> **max-width** option mention the width percentage
>
> **targets** option mention index of field

```
$('#table').dataTable({
    'paging': false,
    'info': false,
    'searching': false,
    'columnDefs': [
      {'max-width': '20%', 'targets': 0}
    ],
});
```

Comment: I don't think columnDefs contains a 'max-width' property, so this might not work...
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs

Comment: As mentioned by @Bartosz, I could not see any max-width option. If it exists in any of the version, please flag the version.